# Ploting perpendicular line to normal of (x,y) coordinates on xy plane?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I want to plot points, which lie in xy plane. The thing is the points are with their given x, y, and z coordinates. I want a plane, not a 3d object. So the planes would be xy, xz, yz. But others can be exemplified from xy plane. What I am asking is xy plane case.

The example points are with their corresponding normals

```
 point A=(10600, 26.662,-0.420), (Normal) N_A = [0.91, 0.36, 0.21]
 point B=(9600, -30.532,-6.208), (Normal) N_B = [0.81, 0.50, -0.30]
 point C=(1000,  10.5, -3.72), (Normal) N_C = [-0.83, -0.54, 0.11]
```

Taking x and y values from these x,y, and z coordinates, how to draw the points in xy plane with their normals and perpendicular lines to the normals?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lz2p0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a projection onto the xy plane, you just need to use the first two coordinates of the points:

```py
A_xy = [A[0], A[1]]
```

Projection on the xz plane is

```py
A_xz = [A[0], A[2]]
```

and so on. The projections can be plotted as an arrow or points on the plane.

If you have a vector `N = [nx, ny]` in a plane, then the line perpendicular to this vector and going through the point `N` is given by:

```py
y(x) = -nx/ny*(x - nx) + ny
```

which you can plot as a function in variable x. Or, calculate start and end points using this function and plot a straight line between calculated start and end points.

Example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

arrow_scale = 100

A = [10600, 26.662,-0.420]
N_A = np.array([0.91, 0.36, 0.21])*arrow_scale

B = [9600, -30.532,-6.208]
N_B = np.array([0.81, 0.50, -0.30])*arrow_scale

xmin = min(A[0], B[0]) - 2*arrow_scale
xmax = max(A[0], B[0]) + 2*arrow_scale
ymin = min(A[1], B[1]) - 2*arrow_scale
ymax = max(A[1], B[1]) + 2*arrow_scale

arrow_A = mpatches.FancyArrowPatch((A[0], A[1]), (A[0] + N_A[0], A[1] + N_A[1]), mutation_scale=10)
ax.add_patch(arrow_A)

arrow_B = mpatches.FancyArrowPatch((B[0], B[1]), (B[0] + N_B[0], B[1] + N_B[1]), mutation_scale=10)
ax.add_patch(arrow_B)

x = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 3)
line_A = -N_A[0]/N_A[1]*(x - A[0]) + A[1]
ax.plot(x, line_A)
line_B = -N_B[0]/N_B[1]*(x - B[0]) + B[1]
ax.plot(x, line_B)

ax.set(xlim=(xmin, xmax), ylim=(ymin, ymax))
ax.set(aspect=1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But what about normals? 

A,B,and, C are the coordinates of the supposed perpendicular lines and normal vectors are pointing where should those perpendicular lines direct. So, how to implement this?

Comment: Sorry, I can only give you the tools to achieve your task. What you want to plot is not specified in your question. It is very unclear...

Comment: Hi, I added a figure for expressing my task. I just randomly directed the normals in the figure for expressing my ideas. Normal vectors should dictate their direction while their locations are determined by A,B,C coordnates and perpendicular lines are the main thing that I want determine using the information of coordinates and normal vectors. Basically they are objects in space.

Comment: I added some code to plot something similar.

Comment: Dear Nechoj, thank you very much for your time and effort.

Comment: Hello, Nechoj, can I ask you another thing? What if I want to add two other values (vectors) that are separated by the perpendicular line to the plot. 
For example a vector V_1 =[-3.21327, 4.317995, -0.480081]
V_2=[-7.645472, 11.540256, -1.632568]

Comment: Do you mean the vectors shall be attached to the lines, that is start from the lines and point to the direction given by the coordinates?

Comment: Yes kinda. I mean their direction should be dictated by their respective coordinates and they attached to the lines. In this example, let's say attached to the line A alone. The line A alone separates the vector values. Particularly their starting points are attached the line. And from their starting point their vector arrow head are directed by their respective vector coordinates.

Comment: And how do you specify the starting point? Same as for the normal vector?

Comment: Well, turns out it is not necessary for being in the perpendicular line, but they can be depicted anywhere in the plot but the condition is their common point should start from the same origin.

Comment: Is there any way to change or control the length of the lines? I changed the values and need to zoom out everything, but the lines are reluctant to change. Also it seems when I try to change the scale of arrow and eventually the length of the lines, the normal's location is changing, which must be fixed.

Comment: The lines are limited by the plot size which is determined by `ax.set(xlim=(xmin, xmax), ylim=(ymin, ymax))`. If you change these parameters, the size of the plot changes.

Comment: Yes, I changed them. I want them to change in predetermined length and free from plot length, which means inside the plot size, which I want to separately determine. Sorry for asking lots of thing and being totally noob for changing it myself. Basically what I am doing is these normal indicates the location of spacecraft and perpendicular lines are shock wave in space. So, these coordinates above are pseudo-coordinates. When I put the real coordinates in space for example coordinates with astronomical unit. Then things are crowded, which is an issue for me.

Comment: If you want to limit the length of a line independent of the plot size, then limit the variable `x`. E.g., try `x = np.linspace(10550, 10650, 3)` for `line_A`.
I think you should experiment with the code and change parameters and see the effect. Also, study the matplotlib docs for the functions used.